# how to fill a DropDown based on another DropDown in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created this code below to fill in the second dropdown users based on teh first dropdown(departments )this is my Ajax request

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#sel_depart").on('change', function(){
            var deptid = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'action.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {depart:deptid},
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(response){

                    var len = response.length;

                    $("#sel_user").empty();
                    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                        var id = response[i]['id'];
                        var name = response[i]['name'];

                        $("#sel_user").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

this is the first dropdown

```
<tr>
                <td>departments/td>
                <td>

                <select id="sel_depart" ><?php foreach($myrow2 as $row){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"> <?php echo $row['ename']?></option> <?php }?>
                 <div class="clear"></div>
                </select>
                </td>

            </tr>
```

this is the second one

```
<tr> 
                <td>users</td>
                <td>
    <select id="sel_user">
        <option value="0">- Select A user-</option>
    </select> 
</td>
</tr>
```

the Ajax sends a request to action.php that contains:

```
if (isset($_POST['depart'])){
$departid = $_POST['depart'];   // department id
if($obj->spinner2($departid)){
    header("location:merchant.php?msg=district fetched ");
}
}
```

this is the function spinner2:

```
public function spinner2($departid){
    $sql="SELECT id,ename FROM district where city_id =".$departid ;
    $arr = array();
    $result = mysqli_query($this->con,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $userid = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['ename'];
        $arr[] = array("id" => $userid, "name" => $name);
    }
     $users_arr=json_encode($arr);
    echo $users_arr;
    return $users_arr;
}
```

When i select a department nothing happens

Comment: If you know how to use browser debugger, please test if the `on('change', function)( { ... })` part really got triggered after changing value in the select box. If so, examine if the success callback is fired.

Comment: nothing was triggered, i added an error callback but nothing was returned

Comment: From my experience, if nothing was trigger, then either the selector is not working or there are some other javascript error blocking. At least most of the time. Do you confirm that the selector can find the correct select box? Is there any other error in your javascript console?